# JDO created from Json in the GAE HRD does not convert back correctly to Json until instance restart

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gson

I'm working on a Android application using the Google App-Engine to store and manage data for the application. Unfortunately I've run into a problem which I don't seem able to solve.

When a user creates a new account a new "Project" is created for them. This project contains tasks, and these tasks are stored in an ArrayList in the Project class. So, in the constructor of the project class everything is instantiated and and the Tasks are created from a text-file with data in Json-format using Gson2.2.2. 
All of this works fine, and if I look in the datastore viewer in the appengine admin console everything looks good. Immediately after creating the account the user is logged on, and when the user logs on the Tasks needs to be sent to the Android-client. This is where it gets weird. When serializing the Tasks back to Json format, they seem to be uninitialized. All the string fields are empty, and the integers are all set to 0, but the correct number of Tasks are being serialized so the list is populated. This problem persists, until I manually shut down the Instance in GAE. When it is restarted with a new request the data is then serialized correctly to Json format and everything works fine. Obviously this is not good, I can't have the server shutdown it's instance every time a new user creates an account, just to be able to serve them the correct data. So, please help me solve this. I've been struggling with it quite a while now. Below is code that accurately reproduces the problem.

```
public class CreateData extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
        if(req.getParameter("name").length() > 1){
            PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
            User u = new User(req.getParameter("name"));
            pm.makePersistent(u);
            pm.close();
            try {
                resp.getWriter().print("User created with name "+req.getParameter("name"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(req.getParameter("name").length() <= 1){
            try {
                resp.getWriter().print("Please supply a name with at least 2 characters");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            try {
                resp.sendError(400);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The User class

```
    public class User {
    public @interface Skip {
        // Field tag only annotation
    }

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent
    private String name;

    @Persistent
    private ArrayList<DataType> data;
    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        data = new ArrayList<DataType>();
        createDataFromJSON();
    }

    public String getDatasAsJSON(){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new MyExclusionStrategy(Key.class)).create();
        Type taskType = new TypeToken<List<DataType>>(){}.getType();
        String json = gson.toJson(this.data, taskType);
        return json;
    }


    public void createDataFromJSON() {
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(new File("WEB-INF/defaults.json"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (fr != null) {
            Type taskType = new TypeToken<List<DataType>>(){}.getType();
            data = new Gson().fromJson(fr, taskType);
        }
    }

    public class MyExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {
        private final Class<?> typeToSkip;

        private MyExclusionStrategy(Class<?> typeToSkip) {
            this.typeToSkip = typeToSkip;
        }

        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            return (clazz == typeToSkip);
        }

        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
            return f.getAnnotation(Skip.class) != null;
        }
    }
}
```

The DataType class

```
public class DataType {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String name;

    @Persistent
    private int points;

    @Persistent
    private int unique;

    public DataType() {
    }

    public DataType(String name, int points, int unique){
        this.name = name;
        this.points = points;
        this.unique = unique;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public int getUnique() {
        return unique;
    }

    public void setUnique(int unique) {
        this.unique = unique;
    }

}
```

Servlet for getting the data

```
public class GetData extends HttpServlet{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        User u = null;
        try{
            u = pm.getObjectById(User.class, name);
        }catch(JDOObjectNotFoundException e){
            try {
                resp.sendError(404);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(u != null){
            String response = u.getDatasAsJSON();

            try {
                resp.getWriter().print(response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the JSON data

```
[ 
    {
      "name": "Hug",
      "unique": 1,
      "points": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "Tug",
      "unique": 2,
      "points": 40
    },
    {
      "name": "Rug",
      "unique": 3,
      "points": 50
    },
    {
      "name": "Jug",
      "unique": 4,
      "points": 100
    },
    {
      "name": "Smug",
      "unique": 5,
      "points": 20
    }
]
```

So, creating a new User with name "Arne" works fine and the objects are created in the HDR. Asking for the objects back from the datastore as Json yields this response

```
[{"points":0,"unique":0},{"points":0,"unique":0},{"points":0,"unique":0},{"points":0,"unique":0},{"points":0,"unique":0}]
```

upon restarting the server instance the same request gives this response

```
[{"name":"Hug","points":20,"unique":1},{"name":"Tug","points":40,"unique":2},{"name":"Rug","points":50,"unique":3},{"name":"Jug","points":100,"unique":4},{"name":"Smug","points":20,"unique":5}]
```

Sorry for the long post, but hopefully somebody is able to point out to me what I'm doing wrong. Many thanks in advance!
Best regards, 
Ivar

Answer (score 0):

To bad nobody seem to be able to answer this, though I've found a work around. I still think this needs a proper solution, but at least I've got it working now by looping through all the objects and assigning a temporary variable with the value from a field in the object. This seems to force them to initialize, and the returned JSON is actually populated with the correct fields.

```
public class GetData extends HttpServlet{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        User u = null;
        try{
            u = pm.getObjectById(User.class, name);
        }catch(JDOObjectNotFoundException e){
            try {
                resp.sendError(404);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(u != null){
            //By adding this seemingly pointless loop
            //the objects will actually return populated fields
            //when converted back to JSON
            for(DataType dt : u.getData()){
                String temp = dt.getName();
            }
            String response = u.getDatasAsJSON();

            try {
                resp.getWriter().print(response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```